# some frames are blank when using switch_frame function

Tags: python, function

I got another question. I must inform you that I am very new and still busy learning as I go. I want to use the switch_frame function in python to switch between different screens with user interaction. I got code for it but when I go to another screen by clicking on a button, that specific screen is blank.

I can upload the .py file if necessary

I have ready some forums but it is still a bit confusing to me.

Comment: @everyone. don't bother, I figured it out, thanks